# How can I find my complete array in Template node

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mustache, node-red

I'm really new to coding with next to no experience, trying to use a Node-Red Template node to create a visual presentation of some simple 2D-coordinates in HTML. Firstly, this is my first time using HTML and Mustache, so these are confusing me. My input as a msg.payload is an array of JSON Objects (if I've understood it correctly) and in those JSON's I've stored X and Y coordinates that would be used to draw dots representing the items. Here's the code from my Template node atm:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Factory floor map</title>
<h><b>Factory floor map</b></h>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function draw() 
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (null==canvas || !canvas.getContext) return;

    var axes={}, ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    axes.y0 = 100;                   // x0 pixels from left to x=0
    axes.x0 = 100;                    // y0 pixels from top to y=0
    axes.scale = 40;                 // 40 pixels from x=0 to x=1
    axes.doNegativeX = false;

    showAxes(ctx,axes);
    plotItems(ctx,axes);

}

function plotItems(ctx,axes)
{
    var ID = 0001;
    for(var i = 0; i < **What here**; i++)
    {
    var X = axes.x0 + axes.scale*{**What here**};
    var Y = axes.y0 + axes.scale*{**What here**};
    drawItem(ID,X,Y,ctx,axes);
    }
}

function drawItem(ID,X,Y,ctx,axes)
{
    var radius = 25;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(Y, X, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    ctx.stroke();
}

function showAxes(ctx,axes) 
{
 var y0=axes.y0, w=ctx.canvas.width;
 var x0=axes.x0, h=ctx.canvas.height;
 var xmin = axes.doNegativeX ? 0 : x0;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(128,128,128)"; 
 ctx.moveTo(x0,y0); ctx.lineTo(w,y0);  // Y axis
 ctx.moveTo(x0,y0); ctx.lineTo(x0,h);  // X axis
 ctx.stroke();
}
</script>

<body onload="draw()">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1600" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I can find single values from my array by using for instance {{#payload.2}}{{X}}{{/payload.2}} in the PlotItems() - function, but I want to be able to go through the whole array, object by object.

Please tell me how I could fix this in the easiest possible way.

To clarify, here is the msg.payload that is the input to my Template node, of which I want o be able to use X and Y values:

```
[ { "_id": "55c099d9067c061d00ff462d", "ID": "0001 ", "X": "100 ", "Y": "4 ", "mass": "10 " }, { "_id": "55c09850067c061d00ff4623", "ID": "0004 ", "X": "15 ", "Y": "5 ", "mass": "10 " }, { "_id": "55c0aaa8067c061d00ff4630", "ID": "5 ", "X": "1 ", "Y": "34 ", "mass": "85 " }, { "_id": "55c0ab78067c061d00ff4631", "ID": "moottori ", "X": "4 ", "Y": "6 ", "mass": "85 " }, { "_id": "55c0b1a7067c061d00ff4645", "ID": "Hannes ", "X": "65 ", "Y": "74.5775 ", "mass": "80 " }, { "_id": "55c1a1e6067c061d00ff4657", "ID": "Roope ", "X": "69 ", "Y": "4 ", "mass": "85 " }, { "_id": "55c1a8b5067c061d00ff4661", "ID": "Roope_2 ", "X": "1 ", "Y": "1 ", "mass": "85 " }, { "_id": "55c1f832067c061d00ff4666", "ID": "Pasi ", "X": "1 ", "Y": "1 ", "mass": "85 " } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mustache is not really good for populating code like this, but you can try something like this

```
...
function plotItems(ctx,axes)
{
    var ID = 0001;
    var X,Y;
    {{#payload}}
    X = axes.x0 + axes.scale*{{X}};
    Y = axes.y0 + axes.scale*{{Y}};
    drawItem(ID,X,Y,ctx,axes);
    {{/payload}};
}
...
```

Comment: That did not seem to work.. :/ is there a better way of doing this, without Mustache?

Comment: Wow hey, removed the [] from your suggestion and it seems to work just fine. Thank you!

Comment: If I was doing it I would load the main body of the page as a static html and then use a Node-RED http request to just get the payload value from with in the page